When shall a curve that connects two points on a surface be a line?
I am preparing to teach 'cross-section of solid structures'. Currently I am studying the cross section of a cylinder.
I take one dot $A$ on the top circle, and dot $B$ on the bottom circle. I think that: if I connect dots $A$ and $B$ , if $AB$ is not one generatrix of the cylinder, then $AB$ must be a curve, but not a line.(If this is not true, please remind me for not telling this mistake to my students:))
And then I come up with a question: When shall a curve that connects two points on a surface be a line?
By the way I remember something about 'developable surface' in Differential Geometry, which is related to the Gauss curvature or something. I remember cones, cylinders are both developable. Are the propositions above true if I only study the cross section of the cones and cylinders?

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. We are looking at curves on the surface of the cylinder and you want to know when such a curve is a line, viewed in the ambient space?

By top or bottom circle, do you mean the bases?

Yes, I mean the bases of the cylinder.Sorry for my poor English. I take dots A and B on the outmost circle of the bases. And I want to know: if i connect A and B, when shall AB be a line and a curve?

Aside from the generators of the cylinder, lines (i.e., geodesics) on the cylinder are helices. Imagine making the cylinder by attaching two opposite edges (say, $XY$ and $ZW$) of a rectangular piece of paper; unroll the cylinder and on this piece of paper any line will turn into a helix on the cylinder. Indeed, if the line starts at a point of $XY$ and hits $ZW$ at a point, the line continues, parallel, at the point of $XY$ corresponding to that point. This process continues as necessary.
